# how to cheked radio button value and mouseover in submit button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
   $('#radio1').attr("checked")

    if($("#radio1").is(":checked"))


    $( "#btnview" ).mouseover(function() {
      $( "div.overlay" ).fadeIn( 300 );
    });

    $( "#btnview" ).mouseout(function() {
      $( "div.overlay" ).fadeOut( 100 );
    });

    }else{

      alert("security")
    }
<label for="radio-1" id="textradio">Aggregate</label>
<input type="radio" name="linebarone" id="radio1" value="a" checked  />
<label for="radio-2" id="textradio">By Security</label>
<input type="radio" name="linebarone" id="radio2" value="s"  checked  />
<td valign="middle" align="left"> <input type="button" style="margin-left:27px" id='btnview' class="button btn-download_mkt" name="view" value=""/></td>
<div class='overlay'style="Padding:4px">Only one month</div>
```

I have some problem when I checked radio button1 and mouseover btnview they fadein and fadeout  in both checkboxes radio1 and radio2. I wanna work only one radiobtn1 and not radiobtn2

Comment: you also have checked in radio 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $("#btnview").mouseover(function() {
    if($("#radio1").is(":checked")) {
      $( "div.overlay" ).fadeIn( 300 );
    }
  });

  $( "#btnview" ).mouseout(function() {
    $( "div.overlay" ).fadeOut( 100 );
  });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dayhu6sj/

**Explanation:**

You want to check if #radio1 is checked **when you hover over the button**, whereas your version checks **when the document is loaded**.

$("#btnview").mouseover sets up an event handler which will fire whenever the cursor hovers over #btnview.  This means that in real terms, your document loads and follows this path:

1. Is #radio1 checked?  Yes it is.
2. Set up an event handler to show the overlay when the mouse hovers over the button.
3. The mouse hovers over the button - fire the event handler.

In my example it instead does the following:

1. Set up an event handler for when the mouse hovers over the button.
2. The mouse hovers over the button.
3. Is #radio1 checked?  If so, show the overlay.

No matter which radio button is selected, however, the overlay should be hidden when the mouse leaves the button.  This ensures you don't end up with the overlay permanently visible if it is somehow displayed while #radio2 is selected.